# Ipad Mini Specfic CSS Media Queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, ipad-mini

I have search a lot about CSS Specfic Media Queries for Ipad mini adn found [this page](http://spirelightmedia.com/resources/responsive-design-device-resolution-reference). Which says this the Ipad Mini have 7.9 in 162 ppi. How to apply this properties in CSS Media Queries. Please help

Comment: This: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPadMini or this: http://halgatewood.com/ipad-mini-media-query/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iPad mini will just inherit the same viewport size as the original iPad. But for more precise, you can target pixel density of the iPad mini, so:

```
/* ipad Mini Portrait */
@media only screen and (width:768px) and (resolution: 163dpi) {

}

/* ipad Mini Landscape */
@media only screen and (width:1024px) and (resolution: 163dpi) {

}
```

Comment: This is technically correct in terms of how to apply resolution to a media query, but it will not do anything as of iOS 6. (see http://jsfiddle.net/egid/DX9eJ/ for an example).

Comment: Actually you can't: "[*] Webkit engine does not support CSS resolution query as in the specification, the use of the non-standard device-pixel-ratio query is needed for browsers Safari, see bug 16832." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution